# Scaling & cropping JPG works almost always, but not for 200x200

Tags: ffmpeg

The FFMPEG command I am using for scaling then cropping is working perfectly in 5 of 6 cases I am processing, but for a reason I don't understand in one case it is not working at all.

dimensions of input jpg file = 774x1032

- dimensions of output jpg file = 1000x1000 --> OK
- dimensions of output jpg file = 400x200 --> OK
- dimensions of output jpg file = 750x200 --> OK
- dimensions of output jpg file = 350x200 --> OK
- dimensions of output jpg file = 400x350 --> OK

dimsions of output jpg file = 200x200 --> ERROR

> ffmpeg -y -i input.jpg -vf
>   "transpose=clock:passthrough=landscape,scale=(iw*sar)*max(200/(iw*sar)\,200/ih):ih*max(200/(iw*sar)\,200/ih),crop=200:200"
>   -q:v 1 output.jpg;

this is running in a batch process, taking as input hundred of files, and always happen the same when scaling&cropping to 200x200...

the ffmpeg output is

> ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
>
> built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
>
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2
>   --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
>
> libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100   libavcodec     58. 35.100 /
>   58. 35.100   libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100   libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100   libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101   libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100   libswresample   3.  3.100 / 
>   3.  3.100   libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
>
> Input #0, image2, from '/_DEV/input.jpg':   Duration: 00:00:00.04,
>   start: 0.000000, bitrate: 144801 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 774x1032 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>
> Stream mapping:
>
> Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))
>
> Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [swscaler @ 050e4100] deprecated pixel
>   format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>
> [Parsed_crop_2 @ 050d9140] Invalid too big or non positive size for
>   width '200' or height '200'
>
> [Parsed_crop_2 @ 050d9140] Failed to configure input pad on
>   Parsed_crop_2
>
> Error reinitializing filters!
>
> Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
>
> Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
>
> Conversion failed!

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Recheck your command and paste it again. Some symbols are missing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when scaling your input 774x1032, it becomes smaller than 200x200, so you cannot crop it to 200x200. That's what the error is telling you.

You could "fix" this by specifying an additional `min(…)` function in the crop width and height, to make sure it crops only to the minimum of `min(ih,200)` and `min(iw,200)`.